# xtype not visible from inside a TabPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a viewport, asnd from inside it I can create a child element by its xtype:
let's call it 'accordion', that I have created and aliased with `xtype:'accordion'` in another file. If I write:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires: [...
                ],

    layout: 'fit',


    items: [ 
              { xtype:'accordion' }

            ]
});
```

the widget is properly created.

If I do the following:

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires: [...
                ],

     items: [
                Ext.TabPanel.create({
                    items: [
                        {
                            title: 'dummy',
                           xtype:'accordion'
                        }
                    ]
                })
                ]
});
```

it does not create the widget ( the symptom is the classic error where widget is not found:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined* 
I can't understand why the widget is not found from inside the TabPanel item list while it is perfectly visible from 'outside'.

Comment: Mis-spoke in my previous answer. Too little info to say for sure. Make a fiddle: `http://fiddle.sencha.com`.

Comment: Maybe I just need to find how extjs became aware of xtype's, it's not clear to em and I did not find in the doc.

Comment: Typically you'll never see the second form. An xtype is just a short name for a class that's more friendly for declaration in a json blob.

Comment: well, maybe I'm wrong, but is widely used: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-xtype

Comment: You can do so, but as I said, typically you'll just want a JSON block. Anyway, without a test case I can't really say much more.

Comment: Because you're forcing construction immediately doing it the second way. In the first way, it will wait til the container component is instantiated (and thus have loaded dependencies).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47933/discussion-between-felice-pollano-and-evan-trimboli)